# Capistrano 3 not showing task description

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, capistrano3

Given a namespaced cap task definition with descriptions:

```
desc 'test namespace'
namespace :test do
  desc 'does something'
  task :something do
    puts 'I do something'
  end
end
```

Neither

```
cap -T
```

Or

```
cap -vT
```

...show the description text.  cap production test:something executes fine. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using these specific cap gems:

```
capistrano (3.0.1)
capistrano-bundler (1.1.2)
capistrano-rails (1.1.0)
capistrano-rails-console (0.1.1)
capistrano-rbenv (2.0.1)
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce your problem, I copied the code above into my `deploy.rb` and `cap -T` shows the description text. Which (exact) version of `Capistrano` are you using? Have you tried updating it?

Comment: See the last task: http://i.imgur.com/ENyDqXf.png

Comment: Hmmm. Wonder if its another cap gem?  Edited the question to reflect my setup

Comment: The latest version of `Capistrano` is `3.2.1`, update and try running `cap -T` again.